# Weird Color appearing in sculpt mode

Tags: mesh, sculpting, artifacts

Good Day,
I was just modeling a face in edit mode and as soon as I went into sculpting workspace to smooth by model a bit, I noticed a weird color on two of the face

[image]

On top of it, as soon as I clicked on the faces to smooth them, they changed color from pink to yellow

[image]

BLEND FILE: https://pasteall.org/blend/8b767a2e2a0945b49e96da4639fd14f7

Comment: Have you tried searching for answers here on Stack Exchange? Maybe this might help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183599/wacky-weird-colors-when-entering-sculpt-mode-blender-v2-83

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer to that is "face sets", it has actually already been answered here:
[part of the mesh become yellow when in sculpt mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187320/part-of-the-mesh-become-yellow-when-in-sculpt-mode)

Comment: I get that blender created new face sets but I didn't use a boolean modifer like everyone asking this question did. Most I did on both those faces was to delete them and change their flow a bit.

Comment: Yes, that was one of the answers I found here... that's why I asked if he even did search here... the link in my comment uses almost the same words like his question.

Comment: So this yellow color is just a blender feature. Nothing is wrong with my mesh?

Comment: @MaulikSharma I don't think there'S something wrong. Well, I don't know what you did to create those face sets (I'm no sculptor most of the time), but disabling them gets rid of the weird color so face sets are the cause. Since I don't use them I'm not going to dig deeper into the functionality of it but I guess there must have been something which made your faces change the color.

Comment: Thnx bro. I'm no sculptor either, I was modeling the face using edit mode and stuff. I went to sculpt mode only to smooth stuff out. Anyhow, u were great help. Thnx again

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, a polygon edges were sharp and also this specific polygon had different color.

The only thing that fixed it was setting *Shade Flat* and then *Shade Smooth* again.